# Is there such a thing as a "supervisor" I can run on a normal x86 PC?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vmware-player

I have a beefy PC. It runs Windows 10 Pro. Windows 10 is a nightmare. Inside of it, I run VMware Workstation 15 Player. Inside that, I run another Windows 10 Enterprise Trial. I use this VM to test sketchy stuff and run any program I don't trust on the host OS.

Is there some kind of minimal "OS" I can install which is a "supervisor" and just provides the bare bones to run and display a bunch of VMs, so that my current host OS Windows 10 Pro *and* my Windows 10 Enterprise both become VMs inside this "supervisor"?

That is, so that they are completely detached from each other and none is the "master" or "host" OS (the "supervisor" is)?

I tried searching for this but found nothing whatsoever. I am aware of Qubes OS, but from my experience, it doesn't even install on most hardware, and it's far from the "minimal supervisor" I'm talking about. And it doesn't even seem like a solid or polished one. I have heard that Windows runs like garbage inside of it, if you even get it to run at all.

I expect that each OS inside this "minimal supervisor" runs extremely closely to the way it runs when it "actually runs".

One major reason I want this, other than the security aspect, is that VMware *still* doesn't even support DirectX 11, over 10 years after it was released, and seemingly are not in a hurry to implement support for it.

Another major reason is that I cannot physically fit multiple actual computers, nor afford them, and this one should be powerful enough and with enough ram (32 GB) to power multiple serious machines. I want to also run some much more secure OS for my "mission-critical" stuff, so that it is entirely separate from my "private" computer or my "test VM".

I have little hope of this existing, let alone be available for free, let alone be good, but I owe it to myself to at least try to ask.

Comment: You mean VMWare ESXi?  Hyper-V Server is another option.  However, in both cases, you would need additional hardware and both are extremely expensive

Comment: @Ramhound Hyper-V Server starts at $0

Comment: While it doesn't address your question, why are you using VMware Workstation when you natively have Hyper-V via `optionalfeatures`

Comment: @grawity - What? [Hyper-V Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/hyper-v-server-2016) most certainly is not free.

Comment: @Ramhound: [Tell that to Microsoft](https://i.imgur.com/acGGcaA.png)

Comment: @grawity - News to me.

Comment: Yea, server licensing is pricey, but HyperV itself is just a feature you enable and doesn't have any price tag of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called a "Hypervisor". For Windows computers there are a few versions of these, relatively mature programs. They support virtual machines on your system.

However, simple "beefiness" is not sufficient to run a Hypervisor. Your computer must have a CPU and BIOS that supports virtualiztion. So, you'll need to look at the specs for your computer and confirm that virtualization is supported on it.

Comment: (It's called that because 'supervisor' already refers to the regular OS kernel/scheduler which manages processes.)